# Nginx: reverse proxy and http to https redirect

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, https, 301-redirect

I currently use a reverse proxy to map `my.domain.com` to a port 5000, but would like to also redirect http traffic to https. I don't want to add SSL cert info, as that's all handled by Cloudflare.

Here's my working reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Here's my broken (`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`) attempt at adding a https redirect to the reverse proxy.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    return 302 https://my.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you expect your webserver to know whether a connection came to Cloudflare over HTTPS or HTTP?  There's basically two options:

1. Cloudflare sets a header, indicating whether or not the request came to them over HTTPS; or
2. Connections to Cloudflare over HTTPS are proxied to you over HTTPS also.

I thought Cloudflare supported option 1, but I can't find any docs on it now.  However, they definitely support option 2, and [you don't even need to buy your own TLS certificate to do it](https://blog.cloudflare.com/universal-ssl-encryption-all-the-way-to-the-origin-for-free/).  I would strongly recommend doing that, and enabling port 443 on your nginx server to use TLS.

Comment: I actually don't know why I posted this; I solved it a few days ago and then came back to my computer and saw I hadn't posted this without remembering that I solved it.  I used the second solution you presented. I'll leave the question up in case others have a similar issue.